# Who is "Dr. MAD"/who composed the default Android ringtones?

Tags: root-access, audio, ringtone, android-13

I found Android's ringtones (in `/system/product/media/audio`), and a lot of them have metadata. The most common name that shows up in the Artist section of the metadata for most ringtones, as far as I know, is "Dr. MAD".

For example, you have "Growl.ogg" (real ringtone in the directory I mentioned above), which has metadata saying the Artist is "Dr. MAD".

Who is "Dr. MAD"/who composed Growl (and all other "Dr. MAD" ringtones)?

<s>Google's song recognition (and Shazam) says it's this: `Nthahouse - Big Jay Mack & Gino Veddy Cheddy`, however I'm not convinced it is because the only audio of it available¹ sounds like someone just looped the ringtone over and over, and placed the vocals of a random song over the top.</s>

It seems as though the people who made that song actually sampled the ringtone.

I've tried googling it, but Google keeps throwing irrelevant results at me. Or maybe I'm not searching the right thing. So, who is this person?

---

¹ [Nthahouse - Big Jay Mack (Growl Ringtone)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OlmHpc-mhk) on YouTube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question from a historical perspective since a Google search threw up a few references to Dr.MAD in the ringtone meta data of several OEM ringtones.

Here is what I found. I cannot vouch for the authenticity.

Tech Product Bangers on Twitter (@techprodbangers) whose profile says

> An account that posted bangers from consumer technology products, such as **ringtones**, BGM and synth demos. Formerly known as Ringtone Bangers + More.

A search for "Dr. MAD" in their Tweets returns these results:

- [Link 1](https://twitter.com/techprodbangers/status/1642161660398825473)

> This is "Sorry", the full song behind the Android 1.0 ringtone, Terminated!
>
> Composed by Sébastien "Bara" Barafani of NewWave Labs, a French company that did ringtones for Google. **(all credited to "Dr. MAD", aka leader Alain Georges)**

- [Link 2](https://twitter.com/techprodbangers/status/1642162508373848064)

> **The mystery behind "Dr. MAD" has been fully solved.** It's a team consisting of:
>
> - Alain "Dr. MAD" Georges
> - Gilles "Zill" Tremellat
> - Christian "T-Jam" Laffitte
> - Noël "Dr. No" Laffitte
> - Charles "Kallaghan" Massabo
> - Sébastien "Bara" Barafani
>
> Thanks to Bara for sending this!

- [Link 3](https://twitter.com/techprodbangers/status/1365762300569923584)

> I'm pretty sure Dr. MAD is just a fake artist name Google used for all of the ringtones by NewWave Labs (which Charles was the director of, and composed some of his own)

- [Link 4](https://twitter.com/techprodbangers/status/1643279916237029376)

> Here is an almost complete composer breakdown of the NWL ringtones. These are all credited to Dr. Mad (Alain), and while he led the team, only 3 of his were used.
>
> The team:
>
> Alain Georges
>
> Sébastien Barafani
>
> Gilles Tremellat
>
> Christian Laffitte
>
> Charles Massabo

| Gilles Tremellat | Sébastien Barafani | Christian Laffitte | Charles Massabo | Alain Georges | No Credit Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Beat Plucker | Bentley Dubs | Bird Loop | Game Over Guitar | Don' Mess Wiv It | Lectro Beat |
| Insert Coin | Cousin Jones | Caribbean Ice | Enter The Nexus | Funk Y'all | Silky Way |
| Medieval Jaunt | Crazy Dream | Ether Shake | Revelation | Miami Twice |  |
| New Player | Curve Ball Blend | Loopy Lounge | Thunderfoot |  |  |
| Romancing the Tone | Dream Theme | Mildly Alarming/Eridani |  |  |  |
| Thriller Three | Friendly Ghost | Ding/Carina/Noisy One |  |  |  |
| Backroad | ***Growl*** | Sitar vs. Sitar |  |  |  |
| Bollywood | Love Flute | Springy Jalopy |  |  |  |
| *...and 8 more* | *...and 8 more* | *...and 15 more* |  |  |  |

(emphasis supplied)